# Docker build returned a non-zero code:1 microsoft/dotnet

Tags: docker, .net-core

**MY docker file Code**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y nuget \
 && apt-get install --reinstall make \
 && apt-get install build-essential -y \
 && apt-get install awscli -y \
 && apt-get install jq -y \
 && apt-get install zip -y \
 && apt-get install -y mysql-server \
 && apt-get install -y mono-complete \
 && apt-get install -y libxml-xpath-perl \
 && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**In step run curl -sL. I'm getting the error,**

```
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y nuget   && apt-get install --reinstall make   && apt-get install build-essential -y   && apt-get install awscli -y   && apt-get install jq -y   && apt-get install zip -y   && apt-get install -y mysql-server   && apt-get install -y mono-complete   && apt-get install -y libxml-xpath-perl   && apt-get install -y nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Anybody Know how to fix this error?**

Comment: Install curl before executing the curl command

Answer (score 0):

Curl is not installed install curl before running a curl command.
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install curl \
 && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
 && apt-get install -y nuget \
 && apt-get install --reinstall make \
 && apt-get install build-essential -y \
 && apt-get install awscli -y \
 && apt-get install jq -y \
 && apt-get install zip -y \
 && apt-get install -y mysql-server \
 && apt-get install -y mono-complete \
 && apt-get install -y libxml-xpath-perl \
 && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: I have tried installing the curl but when I add install curl it is returning error-code: 100. "The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update   && apt-get install curl   && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -   && apt-get install -y nuget
&& apt-get install --reinstall make   && apt-get install build-essential -y   && apt-get install awscli -y   && apt-get install jq -y   && apt-get install zip -y   && apt-get install -y mysql-server   && apt-get install -y mono-complete   && apt-get install -y libxml-xpath-perl   && apt-get install -y nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 100"